# Can't use Selenium with the Company Modified Browser

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

The Company change the browser name to XYZFirefox.exe . And since then, my code is getting an error. "Failed to locate Firefox.exe in the registry". I'm trying it again with the simple code. Does renaming the exe affects it? I would like to sort this first before mailing our IT Dept. Thanks

```
Dim bot As New FirefoxDriver
Dim url As String
url = "https://google.com"
bot.Get url
```

Comment: Does Selenium have a config file where you specify the registry classid (or some other identifying guid) of your choice of browser?

Comment: Hi @Jeeped, Sorry I don't know much about that. I also search it before I post here. Can't find how to specify location. also, the Chrome has error too.

Comment: try http://localhost:4444/grid/console (that took me all of 10 seconds to find via google)

Comment: can you give me the link? Sorry. I'm not that good.

Comment: More a band aid but can you simply switch browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a path to binary:

```
Dim bot As New FirefoxDriver
bot.SetBinary("path to your custom Firefox")
```

Comment: Thanks! the browser is opening. :) But. the url is not loading. :(

Comment: The problem now is the version of the browser.  but this solved my problem.Thanks :)